KeyError in Markov Blanket extraction using PC Algorithm in Python
I'm trying to perform feature selection using the Markov Blanket and PC Algorithm on a dataset. I followed these steps:

Loaded the dataset and applied the PC Algorithm to construct a DAG.
Wrote a function to extract the Markov Blanket of a target variable from the DAG.
I get a KeyError when trying to retrieve the Markov Blanket for a specific node

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from causallearn.search.ConstraintBased.PC import pc
from causallearn.utils.GraphUtils import GraphUtils
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Step 1: Load the dataset
url = 'https://path-to-your-dataset.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(url)`

# Step 2: Drop missing values if necessary
data = data.dropna()

# Step 3: Convert to NumPy format
data_np = data.to_numpy()

# Step 4: Apply the PC Algorithm
pc_output = pc(data_np, alpha=0.05)

# Step 5: Define function to find Markov Blanket
def get_markov_blanket(graph, target_var_index):
    parents = graph.get_parents(target_var_index)
    children = graph.get_children(target_var_index)
    spouses = []
    
    for child in children:
        spouses.extend(graph.get_parents(child))
    
    markov_blanket = set(parents + children + spouses)
    markov_blanket.discard(target_var_index)  # Remove the target variable from the Markov Blanket
    return markov_blanket

# Set target variable index (e.g., X13)
target_var_name = 'X13'
target_var_index = 12  # assuming X13 corresponds to index 12

# Step 6: Get the Markov Blanket for the target variable
markov_blanket = get_markov_blanket(pc_output.G, target_var_index)
print(f"Markov Blanket of {target_var_name}: {markov_blanket}")


Error: 
KeyError: 12

The error happens when I try to run the following line:
parents = graph.get_parents(target_var_index)

I double-checked that the node exists in the graph, but I'm not sure why this error occurs. The DAG seems to be generated correctly, but the issue happens when retrieving the parents or children of the target variable.
My setup:

Python: 3.9
Libraries: causallearn, networkx, pydot, pgmpy

Things I tried:

Checked if the target variable (X13) exists in the graph — it does.
Rebuilt the DAG using different algorithms but faced the same issue.
Ensured all libraries are up to date.

Any insights into why this KeyError happens or how I can correctly retrieve the Markov Blanket would be greatly appreciated!
